# Syntax Error in FROM clause SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is my first time attempting a piece of SQL code and I am getting a multitude of syntax errors depending on which "correction" I try to make. Here is my code:

```
SELECT Max ([CompData Query]![AgedSalary]) AS Percentile
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 Percent [AgedSalary] FROM [CompData Query]![AgedSalary] 
ORDER BY [AgedSalary] ASC);
```

With this I get "Syntax error in FROM clause". After I reopen the SQL code I get the following:

```
SELECT Max ([CompData Query]![AgedSalary]) AS Percentile
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 Percent [AgedSalary] FROM [CompData Query]![AgedSalary] 
ORDER BY [AgedSalary] ASC)  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

Any assistance would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `FROM` clause refer to tables, not columns and subqueries need aliases (names in their own right). So `SELECT Max ([Subquery]![AgedSalary]) AS Percentile
FROM (SELECT TOP 90 Percent [AgedSalary] FROM [CompData Query]
ORDER BY [AgedSalary] ASC) AS Subquery;` should work ( but it'snot tested and my knowledge of ms-access sql syntax might be a bit rusty ... ). Notes: The `MAX` operation on the top 90% of data obviates the subquery. Also,the `Top 90` may deliver more data than you expect in case of ties.

Comment: Well, I got a number! I'm going to verify that the percentile is correct based on the data. Thanks!

Comment: Percentile is correct. Thanks again.